# Between uniform and pointwise convergence

Tags: analysis, continuity

I know that uniform convergence of a sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ on some set $S$ implies continuity of the limit function $f$ on that set. I also know that pointwise convergence of the sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ on some set $S$ does not imply continuity of the limit function $f$ on that set $S$ because if only pointwise convergence is assumed the limit function can be discontinuous.

Now, the natural question that arises is the following:

> What is the weakest known condition on the sequence of
>   continuous functions $f_n$ defined on the set $S$ (if there is
>   additional condition imposed on the set $S$ please, state it, although
>   I believe that such condition should be imposed only on the sequence
>   of functions if the set is nice enough, so you can take the set $S$ to
>   be open or compact) such that that condition guarantees(implies) continuity of the
>   limit function $f$ on the set $S$?

**EDIT:**(14.10.2015) I have the following question which I will ask here so that I do not pose another question as the question that I am going to ask is very closely related to the question asked above and the question is:

> Suppose that $f_n$; $n\in \mathbb{N}$, is a sequence of continuous functions defined on some set $S$ (you can take $S$ to be as nice as possible but as general as possible (open, compact)). What is the weakest known condition on the sequence $f_n$ such that the limit function $f$ is continuous on $S$ if and only if that condition is satisfied?

Comment: _Locally_ uniform convergence implies continuity of the limit. That _may_ be the weakest general condition to imply continuity of the limit.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Thank you.  Is it possible that the "weakness" of the weakest known condition changes if we restrict to different structure of the sets on which sequence is defined, I mean, can it be that the condition changes if we take $S$ to be topological space, or metric space, or compact subset of those spaces?